# Cannot import pandas in Jupyter-Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to import pandas in a Jupyter-Notebook, but I keep getting the following error. BTW, I use conda as my package/virtual environment manager and this error arises regardless of the environment currently active:

[image]

Additionally, when I try to install pandas (again) I am met with the following message:

[image]

I'm aware that my post is similar to this one: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70826479/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-libs-interval) and I would like to try to uninstall the user-level Python, as suggested in the afore mentioned post, but I don't know how and I would greatly appreciate concrete steps to doing so:

[image]

Thank you for your time!

I have tried the following:

- Creating a new conda environment as shown in the following code:

```
conda create --name py37 python=3.7 pandas numpy ipykernel matplotlib jupyter
```

- Uninstalling and reinstalling pandas in the Jupyter-Notebook.
- I have also tried the following code using a different environment:

```
source activate penv
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name penv --display-name "py37k"
```

Comment: try to type in pip freeze in your jupyter notebook, see what version of pandas you have

Comment: Done. I have pandas=1.3.3.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that according to the Anaconda Navigator I have pandas version 1.3.5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085665/in-which-conda-environment-is-jupyter-executing#:~:text=Open%20the%20notebook%20in%20Jupyter,using%20an%20environment%20called%20env_name. try to check which environment you are in